# Using external code for compiled program VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, module, updates

I want to make a simple math problem solver. For this I have to include many functions over the years (because now I'm not quite interested in super difficult problems as I'm interested in interface).
The point is that sometime I'll have to make an update to the program. Usually the software on the user side would have to download the new versions and install it. But the program is quite big and I don't think it's the best way. 
The problem is that I want to transfer only a module of the program or class ,a compiled file , which could provide the data needed for the app. It would contain name-fixed functions so that the app would know which one to call. Is this possible? I'm worried because I read that there will be some problems if the versions of the referenced class are different (the one that is being used with the new one).

Comment: They're called DLLs.

Comment: I know that they're DLLs (i said compiled code..a class maybe). But what about the versions. Won't be there any problems? And as far as I know only class can be compiled into a dll (I tried with a module..couldn't find the dll)

Comment: You don't have to update a version number when you recompile a dll. You can compile modules into DLLs. What you need to do is create a class library project in visual studio, but this class library project can contain modules, classes, and enums.

Comment: It is incumbent on you to keep compatibility in mind when making changes.  That means keeping the interface the same and not changing functions so much that they now do something quite different than before.